# Reexecute task from within UncaughtExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've seen some discussions along these lines, but not a specific answer to my question.  I want to restart a task when a thread dies due to an uncaught exception.  Is it safe to call pool.execute(runnable) from within the UncaughtExceptionHandler set on the dying thread?

Ideally, if the throwable is a RuntimeException, I'd like to just resubmit the runnable to the pool, e.g.

```
pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(monitors.size(), new ThreadFactory() {
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        threadMap.put(thread, (Monitor)r);
        thread.setName(((Monitor)r).getClusterName() + "-monitor");
        thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread th, Throwable t) {
                logger.error("Uncaught exception in thread: " + th.getName(), t);
                if (t instanceof RuntimeException) {
                    Monitor m = threadMap.get(th);
                    if (m != null && m.runCount() < restartMax) {
                        logger.error("Restarting monitor due to uncaughtException: " + m.getClusterName());
                        pool.execute(m);
                    }                        }
            }                   
        });
        return thread;
    }           
});
```

Is there a better way or safer way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The safest option would be to only throw an Runtime Exception which it is fatal.  If a Runtime Exception can be safely ignored why is it not being caught and continued?

It appears that your thread map is like a ThreadLocal, it appears that once one task uses all your restartMax, it will never restart a task again?

The way I would do this is to wrap the executing Runnable.

```
public void submit(final Runnable runnable, final int restartMax) {
    pool.submit(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           for(int i=0;i<restartMax;i++)
               try {
                   runnable.run();
                   break;
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   log.error("Exception", e);
               }
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: The threadMap is just to allow me to get the Monitor/Runnable that corresponds to the Thread with the exception.  restartMax is just to keep from infinitely restarting threads that immediately encounter some persistent error.  This mechanism is meant to recover from some transient exception that hasn't been explicitly handled.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample won't do the job you're trying to address. The runnable that gets passed to the ThreadFactory is not your task runnable but an internal runnable that is used by the ThreadPoolExecutor.

You may want to consider overriding the afterExecute() method instead. This method will always be called, and the first argument will be your runnable, and the second (Throwable) argument will contain the uncaught exception. However, afterExecute() will **not** report the exception if the task is wrapped either explicitly by you with a FutureTask or indirectly via submit(). So, afterExecute() would work only with submission via execute().

```
protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
    super.afterExecute(r, t);
    if (t != null) {
        Monitor m = (Monitor)r;
        if (m.runCount() < restartMax) {
            logger.error("Restarting monitor due to uncaughtException: " 
                    + m.getClusterName());
            execute(m); // exception handling omitted
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I immediately ran into that exact problem.  For the time being I'm using a traditional new Thread/setUncaughtExceptionHandler/start sequence.  It seems both odd and shortsighted that you can't access the Runnable from Thread.   I'll look into your suggestion.   I'm not using FutureTask nor submit, so this should work.   Thanks!

Comment: Even if the thread were created with your runnable passed in, note that it is merely your **first** task that triggered the thread creation. Threads will be long-lived and run multiple tasks. Thus, you won't be able to get the actual runnable that causes a RuntimeException that way reliably.